# Как высчитать нахождение символа до определенного индекса в строке

Tags: python, строки

Суть кода такова:
Если во введенной пользователем строке есть запятая на позиции до 10 (не включительно), выведите ROBOT, иначе выведите HUMAN.
Я решила здесь использовать метод find, но в моем случае код работает неправильно:

```
line = input()

if line.find(',', 0, 8):
  print("ROBOT")
else:
  print("HUMAN")
```

На выводе всегда ответ ROBOT. В чем ошибка?

Comment: `if line.find(',', 0, 10) >= 0:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно с помощью срезов:

```py
line = input()

if ',' in line[:10]:
  print("ROBOT")
else:
  print("HUMAN")
```

Comment: Однострочники: 1) `print("ROBOT" if ',' in input()[:10] else "HUMAN")` 2) `print(["HUMAN", "ROBOT"][',' in input()[:10]])`

Comment: @NowhereMan именно так.

Answer (score 3):

```
str.find(sub[, start[, end]])
```

> Возвращает наименьший индекс в строке, в которой подстрока sub
> находится в пределах фрагмента s[start:end]. Необязательные аргументы
> start и end интерпретируются как в нотации slice. Возвращается -1,
> если подстрока не найдена.

```
if 0 <= line.find(',') < 10:
  print("ROBOT")
else:
  print("HUMAN")
```

В условии `if line.find(',', 0, 8)` если в строке с позиции 0 по позицию 8 будет запятая, то вернется номер позиции, т.е. True

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь понятна ошибка

Comment: Главная проблема это что `-1` - это тоже `True`, любое число, которое не `0` - `True` )

Comment: `if line.find(',', 0, 8) >= 0:` немного эффективнее.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, почему от 0 до 8, я что-то не учел? `Если во введенной пользователем строке есть запятая на позиции до 10 (не включительно)`

Comment: Я ошибся. Последний аргумент должен быть `10`.